# Resize Image to it's original dimension using jQuery Animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to animate an image from 200 x 300px to its original size using jQuery.

I have this picture:

```
var imgHtml = "<img id='bigImg' src='" + bigSrc + "' alt='' style=\"height:200px; width:300px\"/>";
$("#divId").html(imgHtml);
```

And this jQuery code:

```
$("#bigImg").animate({
    height: "400px",
    width: "600px",
},500);
```

It works well, but I actually have to hardcode the future size. I would like to animate to the original size.

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try doing this

**HTML**

```
<div id="divId">Loading</div>
<input id="submit" type="button" value=" Click Me " />
```

**JavaScript**

```
var bigSrc = "Image Source";

var img = new Image(),
    oWidth, oHeight;

img.onload = function() {
    oWidth = this.width;
    oHeight = this.height;
    this.width = 300;
    this.height = 200;
    this.id = "bigImg";
}
img.src = bigSrc;

$("#submit").click(function(e) {
    $("#divId").append(img);
    $("#bigImg").animate({
        height: oHeight,
        width: oWidth,
    }, 500);
});​
```

[Check this demo jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dAzyj/5/)

You can tweak to suit you. Hope this helps you.

Comment: I am trying. so you're creating a new image at the beginning ? Maybe I could use it to replace imgHtml ? (see code update)..

Comment: Good point... Check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/dAzyj/4/) jsFiddle. Also updated my answer. Let me know if it works out or not.

Comment: I am trying. I will tell you if it works in a couple of seconds

Comment: While the image is getting download on client machine you can put some message or gif which indicates image is getting downloaded. Of the topic I'm South Park fan :)

Comment: Well, The image must appears 300 x 200 when you click on #submit and then be resized to its original value. This code pre-load the image. Excuse me, I didn't think it was important to specify..

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I see what you mean now.

`$("#bigImg").width()` will return the width in px, and height will do similar. You can also use `.outerWidth()` and `.innerWidth()` to include padding/border or just padding, respectively.

From your code, you've already changed the original dimensions of the image by using inline styles. Instead, save the image dimensions, change the image to 200 x 300px in jQuery, do what you want to it, then change it back to original dimensions:

```
var originalWidth = $("#bigImg").width();
var originalHeight = $("#bigImg").height();

$("#bigImg").css({
    width: '200px',
    height: '300px'
});

//Do whatever you meant to do here, the when you're finished...

$("#bigImg").animate({
    width: originalWidth,
    height: originalHeight,
},500);
```

jQuery documentation: 
http://api.jquery.com/animate/ or http://api.jquery.com/category/dimensions/

Comment: I edit my post, my image is generated. Look at my code, you will understand that I don't have the initial size..

Comment: This will give little problem, for some moment image will be shown with original dimension, until the css is modified with jquery. [Check this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dAzyj/2/)

Comment: Ah, I didn't know you could get the dimensions straight from .onload! So that reads the dimensions before applying the style= tags?